# How JpaRepository.save() method work internally

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity - Workflow

```java
@Entity
Workflow {
    ...
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "workflow", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Tasks> tasks
    ...
}
```

And another Task entity with

```java
@Entity
Task {
    ...
    Status status;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_id")
    Workflow workflow
    ...
}
```

Both entities have defined `JpaRepository`.

```
WorkflowRepo extends JpaRepository<Workflow, Id>
TaskRepos extends JpaRepository<Task, Id>
```

Now, to update the status of `Task` which method is efficient?

```
workFlowRepo.save(workflow) // saving the whole workflow object which internally updates task also
```

Or

```
tasRepo.save(task) // saves only task object in repo.
```

Is there any major performance difference between the above two techniques.

i.e. How does `JpaRepoitory.save()` will work in these conditions?
Will it run the update statement on the whole thing or just update the changed object?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have cascade annotations you have to save the `task`.

If you had an appropriate cascade annotations the performance difference depends on a ton of things like the exact mapping of the entities, the state of the entities and the state of the underlying `EntityManager`. 
In general it will be neglectable though compared to the unavoidable time needed to actually save the entities.

Regarding how `save` works:

The `save` operation performs a `merge` on the underlying `EntityManager`. 
This on its own doesn't perform any SQL but just returns a managed version of the entity.
If that isn't already loaded into the `EntityManager` it might do this or it might identify the entity as a new one and make it a managed entity.
It then might have to perform an insert statement or a select in order to obtain an id.

If the saving didn't happen as a side effect of the above it will only happen when the `EntityManager` gets *flushed*. 
This typically happens at the end of the transaction but might also happen before a query gets executed or when explicitly asked for.

*Note: It looks like you want a bidirectional relationship, but you actually have two separate relationships. One from `Workflow` to `Task` and one back from `Task` to `Workflow`.*

Comment: Hi Jenes, the Cascade is there for tasks and I do have a bidirectional relationship, I've missed while while copying. Sorry

Comment: Now, as I have cascade and bidirectional relationship, which method to update the status of one of the task will be efficient. Saving the whole workflow or only saving the status of that task.